# Graph immersed into the plane with segments as edges and we search for matching with no edges intersecting

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, perfect-matchings

There are some points in the plane and some of them are connected with segments between them. We look at this structure as a graph immersed into the plane where the points are the vertices and the segments are the edges. We search for a maximum matching with no edges intersecting each other.

Are there any results about this question — NP-hardness or algorithm or characterisation even for some cases (the one case I see is when the graph is bipartite and the vertices of the two classes are on two parallel lines respectively)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the in-press 2012 paper,
"Non-crossing matchings of points with geometric objects,"
by Aloupis et al.
([Elsevier link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772112000788); [Prelim. PDF link](http://www-ma2.upc.es/seara/matching_submitted%2520.pdf)) will help,
either directly or through its references. (I have only passing familiarity with the contents
of this paper myself.)

          
[image: Figure 1]
<sub>(source: [els-cdn.com](http://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0925772112000788-gr001.sml))</sub>